# Only show current category post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, categories, loop

I have created a custom loop using `WP_Query` to show posts associated to a custom post type I created.

```
<?php
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'     =>      'scp_content'
  ));
?>

<?php 
  if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <section id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>" class="main-content">
      <h2><?php the_field( 'section_heading' ); ?></h2>
      <div class="container-fluid col-lg-9">
        <p><?php the_field( 'section_content' ); ?></p>
      </div>
    </section>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Each post has one specific category assigned and all categorized posts can be viewed when the said category is clicked via a category menu that I created.

**The issue:** Regardless of which category I click, I am shown all posts. I have tried implementing: `get_category();`, `get_query_var();`, `get_the_category();` and `is_category();` within my loop to try and specify posts shown via current category selected but to no success.

Assuming I am using these function incorrectly, how can I show the current category posts when a user clicks on the specific category in the menu?

Comment: You don't have to create the queries yourself. If you link to a category archive, WordPress generates the query for you automatically, you just run the normal loop in the template. Your custom post type will work the same way if you set `has_archive` to true, you don't need the custom query you have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `get_the_category();` inside the WordPress loop and pass the `get_the_ID()` function which will get the current post ID in the loop.

`get_the_ID()` will return the post id and whereas the `the_id();` will just display.

```
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  $the_query->the_post();

     $category_array = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );

     print_r( $category_array );

  endwhile; 

 endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hopefully, the above code will solve the issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can create a variable with the above function and hook it into my array?

        $current_cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );

        $the_query = WP_Query( array (
           'post_type'    =>    'scp_content',
           'cat    =>    $current_cat`
        ));

Comment: You can only use the `get_the_ID();` inside the loop. I have updated the code. Also `get_the_category( get_the_ID() );` will return categories in a array format.